# How to use the symbol \angle at the section title

Tags: sectioning, symbols

I want to use the symbol `\angle` at a section title but I get an error message:

> ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. to be read
>   again $ l.9   \section{Second section: $\angle$ }

See the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    This is my document.

    \section{First section: $S=\sin(\alpha)$}
    Use $\angle$ at normal text.

    \section{Second section: $\angle$ } %Here the error occurs
    Text at second section.

\end{document}
```

So the question is, how may I use the `\angle` symbol in a section title?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must `$\protect\angle$` in the section heading.  What this means is that `\angle` is a "fragile" command and must be protected from premature expansion.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    This is my document.

    \section{First section: $S=\sin(\alpha)$}
    Use $\angle$ at normal text.

    \section{Second section: $\protect\angle$ } %Here the error occurs
    Text at second section.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, you can `\robustify\angle` once in the preamble (with `etoolbox`).  Then, it need not be protected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\angle
\begin{document}
    This is my document.

    \section{First section: $S=\sin(\alpha)$}
    Use $\angle$ at normal text.

    \section{Second section: $\angle$ } %Here the error occurs
    Text at second section.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Formidable answer. In my MWE both methods worked, but in my real document the first one with `\protect` was still flawed. Nevertheless, `\robustify` fixed the error completely. Thanks for quickly answering. :)

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus How much protection a fragile argument needs depends on the actual usage.

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus Here's a useful description: https://texfaq.github.io/FAQ-protect.html.  Also many questions on this stackexchange site, as well, can be searched.

Comment: @StevenBSegletes Great! Actually, I had not enough with the answer. I wanted to understand the mechanism behind—I will read it, for sure!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer was correct at the time it was written (2018) but for LaTeX releases from 2019 on, this is not needed as `\angle` along with many other commands is now robust so `\protect` is not needed (although does no harm).

The test document in the question runs without error in current releases, so if readers come here as they get that error, a better answer is to update the TeX system.